# How to debug a script - "webpack serve --config webpack.config.js"

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, webpack

I have just started working on webpack. Needed to know how do I add a debugger for the start script in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "webpack serve --config webpack.config.js",
}
```

I had used
`node --inspect` earlier. But, not sure how do we debug a webpack.

I tried to search for resources online, but most of them have only told about
`webpack --debug <node_modules_path>`

How do we debug while serving the webpack?